Transform connecting powers of integration and differentiation operators
Just by a chance, I found the following power series identity, which holds for any analytic function $F(\cdot)$, nonnegative integer $m$, and constants $u,v$ not depending on indeterminates $z,t$:
$$\bigg(\int \mathrm{d}t\bigg)^m e^{(1-uz)t} F(e^{-vzt})\bigg|_{t=0} = \big(1-z\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\big)^{-m} e^{ut} F(e^{vt})\bigg|_{t=0}.$$
It is not hard to prove, but I suspect that it may be a partial case of some general transform. Any pointers will be appreciated.
